# Is it possible to have a hypervisor with Nvidia SLI 980 pass-through gaming setup?

Tags: virtualization, sli, hypervisor

I am looking into reformatting my computer. I would really love to get rid of Windows finally and only use Linux for gaming/work. Sadly I am not sure this is close enough to be a reality yet.

I am looking into setting up some hypervisor form of software where I can easily switch between Windows and Linux without rebooting my machine for ease of use. My only concern/problem is getting optimal performance on my [Nvidia SLI 980](http://www.nvidia.com/content/geforce-gtx/GTX_980_User_Guide.pdf) setup for when I want to play games on Windows.

From what I have been reading online Nvidia has some pass-through technology being worked on but it is not yet available to the public. Are there any pass-through methods available or something that will help me to get the best performance out of these cards if I want to play a very graphic intensive game still?

I would prefer to stay away from running a virtual machine in one operating system for the other for security/performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are into gaming, I would suggest you just leave a small partition for windows.

For the sake of curiosity, why do you think you need a HyperVisor vs a regular linux distro? Is it because you feel you can make better use of the machine hardware?

Honestly if this is for gaming purposes I think the best is to keep windows and just boot into it when needed. Or, if you spend most of your time gaming then just define the tasks you need to take care of in linux and find alternatives (linux VM, VPS, etc)

Sorry if I missunderstood the question. This comes from most of my linux friends being gamers and all arriving to the conclusion that is just simpler to dual boot. And a couple of them only needed the command line so they own a VPS which they work via SSH. (And some who have the extra money have their gaming pc/laptop and a separate linux machine)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is mostly what I was looking for. Was trying to see if there were any better alternatives to dual booting, but it does not seem like there currently are.

I use linux more than windows, but my goal was to not have to re-open all of the applications I use on each boot cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with VMware ESXi, I've done it with Windows 10 build 1511. Nvidia's drivers wont let GeForce drivers start in a VM, so you need to add `hypervisor.cpuid.v0` to the VM's VMX file to prevent it from detecting it is running in a virtualized environment, and then patch the drivers with DifferentSLI Auto.